# call_user_func_array() error on front end

Tags: errors, migration

I've read the other posts about this issue, but mine is different in one fundamental way... there is no function defined in the error. It reads like this:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name in /home/ovbar/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496

I've never seen this error without a function defined so I'm at a loss. I moved it using the `All-in-One WP Migration` plugin. Any ideas? Here's what I've done so far:

- I've already checked for hard-coded urls just to be sure, and there aren't any.
- Deactivating all plugins still shows this error.

Every other aspect of the site works fine. This error only displays on the front end.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try temporarily adding debugging stuff to the core, eg at `add_action` in "wp-includes/plugin.php" line 431 putting `if ( empty( $function_to_add ) ) echo '<pre>', debug_print_backtrace(), '</pre>';`.

Comment: I tried that, to no avail. I also tried using a try catch around the failing statement on line 496 but I get the same error.

Comment: The try/catch should do it though if you turn it into an exception - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning

Comment: I ended up just adding `error_reporting(0);` to the bottom of my wp-config file. It's only for that theme, and I'm going to be reworking it anyway. I went through the theme (poorly built) and commented out all of the `add_action()`s and the error still displayed, but if I switch themes it's gone. So for now, turning off warnings will do.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully tracked this problem by adding

```
error_log("wp-hook: ". print_r($the_, true));
```

within apply_filters in wp-includes/wp_hook.php

The task is then to look at the function calls (the data inside $the_) surrounding the "PHP Warning: call_user_func_array()". It will be the one directly ahead of the warning, but you may need to look at calls after or before to determine which file is causing the problem (a filter call to an undefined function).

Note also that the problem will arise if the function exists, but has no code, like:

```
function create_menu() {
    //oops, there's no code here
}
add_action('admin_menu',array($this,'create_menu'));
```

Comment: In response to edits of my answer: I think it's important to know that the error_log needs to go in the apply_filters function in the wp_hook.php file.